# Can we create a file in GCP storage?

Tags: file, google-cloud-platform

I need to create a empty file in GCP but I only see Upload options. Is there a way I can achieve this? or we can only upload filestream to GCP?

Comment: create an empty file in your local machine and upload it to gcp?

Comment: Are you using a particular language or library? Which storage method are you using - Cloud Storage or something else?

Comment: @Prisoner I am using C#. I need to create an empty file along with another file upload

Comment: Empty file where? Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Yes Google storage bucket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [StorageClient.UploadObject()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_UploadObject_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_IO_Stream_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_UploadObjectOptions_System_IProgress_Google_Apis_Upload_IUploadProgress__) and pass it an empty Stream.